# How to clear Crystal Reports cache?

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I have used Crystal Reports in which I have displayed data using the drag and drop wizard. Now when I want to display the report on combo box selection change, when there is only one item in the dropdown it shows proper result. But when there are more than one items in the dropdown, it shows me report which displays repeated entries. I think I need to clear the selection on selection change. I have not used any dataset or datatable.

How do I clear the report?

I've tried

```
pay.SetParameterValue("Bill", txtBill.Text);
crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = pay;
this.crystalReportViewer1.ParameterFieldInfo.Clear();
crystalReportViewer1.Refresh();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
ReportDocument.Close()

crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = null;

crystalReportViewer1.Refresh();
```

Comment: the close() is not available under ReportClientDocument

Comment: I have changed the code, try assigning null to report source before assigning new source, hope it will resolve your issue